# static_cast required when using std::get with enum class

Tags: c++, templates, implicit-conversion, stdtuple

According to the [c++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/get), the template parameter of `std::get` is a `std::size_t`. Why does one need an explicit cast when such a parameter is an `enum class` with base type `std::size_t`, instead of having an implicit conversion?

See following example

```
#include <tuple>

enum class labels : std::size_t { red, green, blue };

int main()
{
  std::tuple<int, int, double> a;
  // std::get<labels::red>(a) = 0;
  std::get<static_cast<std::size_t>(labels::red)>(a) = 0;
  std::get<static_cast<std::size_t>(labels::green)>(a) = 0;
  std::get<static_cast<std::size_t>(labels::blue)>(a) = 0;

  return 0;
}
```

Uncommenting the line gives rise to a compilation error (gcc 7.3.0)

```
tuple.cpp:8:26: error: could not convert template argument ‘red’ from ‘labels’ to ‘long unsigned int’
   std::get<labels::red>(a) = 0;
```

Comment: That's the main feature of `enum class`es: they forbid implicit conversions from and to integral types.

Comment: That's the main difference of `enum class` vs. `enum`... `enum class` cannot be implicitly converted to any other type, you need to cast it explicitly.

Comment: @francesco You could just write std::tuple<int, int, double> a = {};

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `enum class` (as opposed to simple `enum`) is not implicitely convertible to numeral type. You need to explicitely cast it to obtain the numeric value, for example using `static_cast<>()`.